# How to recognize ZFS on a block special file with the 'file' command?

Tags: filesystems, zfs

Asking the `file` command to recognize an ext3 filesystem is no problem:

```
# file -s /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=1b3e5f83-ac18-47d6-86bc-9fced1f8f67a, volume name "transcend3" (needs journal recovery) (large files)
```

But doing this on a ZFS pool vdev results in nothing:

```
# file -s /dev/dm-3
/dev/dm-3: data
```

How do I recognize a ZFS data? I'm trying to make sure that I am not just typing the wrong password for my dm-crypt device.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which one of them is [more] correct, either

`URL=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zeek/bromagic/master/database/zfs`

or

`URL=https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=752998;filename=zfs;msg=10`

In the end:

```
sudo cp -a /etc/magic /etc/magic.bak
wget -O - "$URL" | sudo tee -a /etc/magic
```

Should do the trick. Please comment which one of them has worked for you.

Comment: AFAICT, those are magic files for zfs dumps, not to ZFS block devices. In any case, neither of them match on block devices used as ZFS devices in my tests.

Comment: Yup, neither matches my ZFS devices too.

Comment: Sorry guys, I couldn't find any more file/mime definitions for ZFS on the net. Perhaps someone could create one.